# An objcopy equivalent for Mac / iPhone?

Tags: macos, arm, darwin, binutils, objcopy

I would like to rename symbols inside object files (.o) with something that would be the Mac equivalent of binutils' `objcopy --redefine-syms` tool.

I found no `arm-apple-darwin10-objcopy`. I tried the MacPorts' `arm-elf-binutils` port and also tried to play a bit with `otool` and `segedit` without much success.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you OK with defining aliases, which means that older symbols will still exists ?

Comment: how about `brew install binutils` and `gobjcopy`? eg: `gobjcopy --redefine-sym _D4main9foo_test1FZv=_foobar main.o main2.o`; NOTE: the resulting executable seems wrong but `nm main2.o | grep _foobar` works

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for [Agner Fog's **objconv**](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv).

From the [announcement](https://web.archive.org/web/20161004105930/https://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-x86/2008/Jun/msg00000.html):

> I have now finished making full support for Mach-O files in the object file converter mentioned in my previous posts. You may use it as a replacement for the missing objcopy utility.
>
> Objconv can be used for the following purposes:
>   Convert object files and library/archive files between Mach-O, ELF, COFF and OMF formats for all x86 and x86-64 platforms.
>
> Change symbol names in object files, make symbols weak, add alias names to symbols.
>
> Build, modify and convert static library files (*.a, *.lib) across platforms (Mac, Linux, BSD, Windows)
>
> Dump object files and executable files
>
> Disassemble object files and executable files. Very good disassembler.

- [objconv manual](http://www.agner.org/optimize/objconv-instructions.pdf)
- [objconv.zip - source](http://www.agner.org/optimize/objconv.zip)

Comment: from the FAQ: "11.3 Is it possible to convert files for ARM?
No. A lot of people have asked about this, so there is obviously a need for such a tool, but I
am not gonna make it. Objconv supports only files for x86 and x86-64 architectures. It will
require a major rewrite of objconv to make a converter for ARM files."

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm resurrecting this post from the dead, but...

I have a sudden need to do this as well, and discovering that `objcopy` doesn't work on OSX was a bit of a shock. But I *think* it's possible to use `ld` to achieve the same effect:

```
ld -r input.o -o output.o -alias oldsymbol newsymbol -unexported_symbol oldsymbol
```

This really just creates an alias for the symbol under a new name and hides the old one.

I haven't had a chance to do much testing yet, but looking at the output file with `nm` shows it seems to be doing the right thing.

Comment: This command deletes all debug symbols. Do you know how to copy them from the original object file?

Comment: `objcopy` can rename symbols T (text section symbol) and U (undefined) symbols. However, your `ld` solution can only handle the former.

Answer (score 1):

objconv does not currently work for ARM, so this option is not available for iPhone.  It should be no problem to use objconv from elf to mach-o for mac osx x86/x64 though.  Let me know if you found a solution for ARM