# Get a reference to local symbol (i.e. make it external)

Tags: ios, linker, extern, symbols, mach-o

I have a static library, where one of the objects defines a symbol:

```
nm mylib.a
...
00007340 t _a_local_symbol
...
```

I need to access the function from my C code. Obviously, I don't have the source code for the library, so I can work only with the archive file that I have at hand.

This is further restricted by iOS linker.

A bit more context. The library is Objective-C++, the function in question is pure C. I don't have original headers, but I've got the function signature restored.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail and context to the question please?
Is the library pure C or objective-c? Are you wanting to call a function that isn't exposed in a header file, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

`objcopy` has a flag to do what you want:

`--globalize-symbol <name>     Force symbol <name> to be marked as a global`

Not sure whether objcopy works on iOS object files though.

Comment: Objcopy is part of GNU binutils, and it seem to work with ELF only. Here's more on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475854/an-objcopy-equivalent-for-mac-iphone

Comment: Actually, at this point I've figured that I can possibly do it on the object file side, as there seem to be no direct solution for linker.